# Take the inputs from the user

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hello this function is taking the inputs from a file how to change it that can the user select his own inputs btw it's taking char inputs by maximum 20 chars

I need a simple code just using cin and cout please:

```
void readInitialChar(){
//declaring variables
int i=0,j=0;
//declaring stram
ifstream fin;
//opening file
fin.open("sample.txt");
//declaring variables
string line;
//taking input
getline(fin, line);
//loop for itearting through the each char
while(line[i]!='\0' && j<20){
//checking for space
if(line[i]!=' '){
//if not then store it in array
arr[j]=line[i];
//increment
j++;
  
}
    //increment
i++;
 }
}
```

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: Hi, do you want to read the inputs from a file? or just use cin?

Comment: You never increment `i` for some reason.

Comment: just cin to take from user

Comment: @tadman by mistake when copying the code it's incremented now

Comment: Incremented, but indented would help even more. That mistake would have stood out more clearly.

Comment: Just`cin>>x` to whichever variable (supposing variable x is declared) and `cout<<x` to see what was input. Like @tadman said use indentation that will help you and others immensely.  Try not to copy as it greatly hinders your learning process.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to write a loop that reads the user input as a string and that input shall then be processed? And a limitation is that the input has less than 20 characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  for (std::string input; std::cin >> input;) {
    // you could process your input here. If the input should still be shorter than 20 characters,
    // you could check for different cases:
    if (input.length() < 20) {
      // do whatever you want to do with the input here, e.g., print it:
      std::cout << "User input is: " << input << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Input has not less than 20 characters." << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```